# django ModelFormSet returns with errors, want to display all forms except the empty ones

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

Using django 1.4, I have a ModelFormSet with no initial instances and extra and max set to 6:

```
# forms.py
ChildFormSet = modelformset_factory(Child, formset=FirstRequiredModelFormSet, exclude=('family_application', 'exported', 'index',), extra=6, max_num=6)
child_queryset = Child.objects.none()
```

When the user first visits the page, I use jquery to show only one blank form (fieldset). The user can press a button to show the rest of the forms. If the form returns with validation errors, I can use jquery to find the fieldsets that have s of class errorlist and show all those fieldsets. However, I also want to show any fieldsets that contain valid data. I could inspect all the  elements in each fieldset to see if they have values, but that seems clunky. Django knows when a form has changed, so I thought I'd add a prefix to those forms so that I could spot them in the html:

```
class FirstRequiredModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstRequiredModelFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.forms[0].empty_permitted = False

    def clean(self):
        super(FirstRequiredModelFormSet, self).clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.has_changed():
                form.prefix = '-'.join(('modified', form.prefix))
```

The problem is that the way I'm overriding clean() somehow causes the submitted data to get lost when the form returns with errors (it comes back without initial data). If I return early by checking for validation errors first like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if any(self.errors):
        return
    super(FirstRequiredModelFormSet, self).clean()
    for form in self.forms:
        if form.has_changed():
            form.prefix = '-'.join(('modified', form.prefix))
```

, the data is still there, but of course then the prefix doesn't get added. I thought of using is_bound instead of has_changed(), but it seems that all the forms are bound from the start, I'm guessing because they're ModelForms.

Any ideas why overriding BaseModelFormSet.clean() to add prefixes causes the returned form's initial data to get lost?

Comment: Are you returning self.cleaned_data at the end of your override?

Comment: No, you don't need to for a ModelFormSet. The default implementation just checks that the new objects don't violate the model's unique constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser posts the forms back to the server Django is using the prefix to identify which form belongs with which Child object. I think you're messing with that system by adding your own prefix.

I would suggest using a different system for identifying modified forms. I think you should be able to use the `has_changed()` method in your template, so you could do something like -

```
<form class="{% if form.has_changed %}changed{% endif %}">
```

(note the lack of brackets when you call a method in a template).

Comment: I didn't realize I could call the form's methods from the template. If this works, this will be cleaner solution anyway. I'll try it on Monday.

Comment: Assuming you meant form.has_changed, this works. Thanks Aidan!